# How do I continue to find the critical points of this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\ f(\theta) = 6\sec \theta + 3 \tan \theta $

with the domain $\ 0 < \theta < 2π $

Here is what I get for the derivative:
$\ {dy \over d\theta} = 6\sec \theta \tan \theta + 3 \sec^2 \theta $

Then I set the derivative to 0:
$\  6\sec \theta \tan \theta + 3 \sec^2 \theta = 0 $

Factor: $\ 3\sec \theta ( 2\tan \theta + \sec \theta) = 0 $

How do I solve it from here? find the critical points from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = 0$$ $$ \iff \sec\theta = 0$$ $$\text{or}$$ $$2 \tan \theta + \sec \theta = 0 \iff2\tan\theta = -\sec\theta\iff 2\sin \theta = -1 \implies \sin \theta = -\frac 12$$

Comment: Note that no solutions exist to $\sec \theta = 0$, hence we need only consider when $$\sin \theta = -\frac 12 \iff \theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac {-1}2\right) \implies \theta = \dfrac {11}6 \pi$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2\tan\theta+\sec\theta=0\iff 2\tan\theta=-\sec\theta$$

$$\iff 2\sin\theta=-1\text{ as }\frac{\tan\theta}{\sec\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}1=\sin\theta$$

$$\implies \sin\theta=-\frac12=\sin\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$

$$\theta=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Find $n$ such that $0<\theta<2\pi$